# reverse proxy on apache2 and ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, proxy

So I created a reverse proxy on the abc.com server where xyz.com/users/sign_in will proxy for "/users/sign_in" so that in url it would show abc.com/users/sign_in. And that worked fine in ubuntu and apache2. After enabling proxy in ubuntu, I set my virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName abc.com
        ServerAlias www.abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/public_html
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/public_html/>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Deny from all
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass /users/sign_in http://xyz.com/users/sign_in 
        ProxyPassReverse /users/sign_in http://xyz.com/users/sign_in
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/abc.com-error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/abc.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now here's the problem. /users/sign_in does a post request on the other server (the xyz server), that is, its an actual form that gets submitted, and the code on the other server redirects the user to the root of the website. Here's the log from the other server:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for IPADDRESS at 2012-02-22 14:59:13 -0500
  Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "remote"=>"true", "commit"=>"Login", "user"=>{"email"=>"xyz@xyz.net", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "subdomain"=>"", "remember_me"=>"0"}}
Redirected to http://abc.com/
Completed 302 Found in 110ms
```

So this is actually good it appears on the surface. The other server responded, signed the user in and then redirects them to the root url. The problem is they dont get redirected to the root url: xyz.com (which contains the application code i want them to see). Rather they get redirected to abc.com which is the other server.

But if I add a proxy for xyz.com in addition to xyz.com/users/sign_in in the abc.com server, then I will have a big problem. How will the browser know whent the user wants to see abc.com (the actual site content) and xyz.com (the application that I want to load after the /users/sign_in is invoked).

I am completely stuck on this and open to any suggestions.

Comment: Do you control abc.com?

Comment: Is the intent to have the redirect send the user so they're pointing directly to `xyz.com` after they've successfully signed in?  Or do you want to keep their browser pointing to `abc.com` and serve them the content from the `xyz.com` server?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I want to keep their browser pointing to abc.com and serve them the content from the xyz.com server.

Comment: @JohnMerlino Gotcha.  So to be more specific: you want someone who's logged in on `xyz` successfully to be proxied to `xyz` for `/` (and all other content on the site?  Or just `/`?) - while someone not logged in should get the content from the docroot local to the `abc` server?  Did I get that right?  And if so: what's the session cookie from the `xyz` server look like?

Comment: @ShaneMadden you are exactly right. When someone is logged in on xyz, they should be proxied to xyz for all content of the site, while someone not logged in should get the content from the docroot local to the abc server. The session cookie from xyz looks like this (according to google chrome browser): Cookie: _session_id=d41c9ab959dc9198a0d6ef6bebbbacba

Comment: actually to make things easier i want to redirect to subdomain abc.com/tracking rather than just abc.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm - interesting deployment give this a shot.  This will proxy all requests to the `xyz` server if the client sends a `_session_id` cookie.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} _session_id=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://xyz.com/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse / http://xyz.com/
```

Put it below your existing `ProxyPassReverse` configuration; the order is significant for the `ProxyPass` directives.

This seems pretty fragile - I'm sure you have a reason for doing it like this, but is there no other way to separate the authenticated and unauthenticated sections of this application?

---

**Edit:** To have the `xyz` content served from `/tracking` instead:

```
ProxyPass /users/sign_in http://xyz.com/users/sign_in
ProxyPassReverse /users/sign_in http://xyz.com/users/sign_in
ProxyPass /tracking/ http://xyz.com/
ProxyPassReverse /tracking/ http://xyz.com/
```

Comment: thanks for respoonse, I think when you answered this question I responded with a comment above, saying that if its easier, i can redirect to abc.com/tracking

Comment: if i redirect to abc.com/tracking, would this change the code above? thanks for the responsers

Comment: So `abc.com/tracking/` should deliver content from `xyz.com/`?

Comment: yes abc.com/tracking/ should deliver content from xyz.com/

Comment: i tried your initial solution and got this: The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: xyz.com (Note that i replaced xyz.com with the real site address)

Comment: Ok - try the new edit in the answer.

Comment: Is it using DNS for resolving the name that it's proxying to?  Use the server's IP address instead - or at the very least put `xyz.com` in the hosts file.  Anyway, that error should be occurring even with your original config if it's occurring at all.

Comment: I decided to go with initial solution again because the redirect to /tracking would have forced me to change code in the other app so to diz the "dns lookup failure" issue, I changed the domain name to the ip address and now I have this error: Reason: Error reading from remote server

Comment: I googled the above error and they mention updating apache to version 2 or higher but I do have version 2: Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Does the `xyz` server care what it gets for a host header?

Comment: it almost works completely. It successfully logs in with reverse proxy. However, when signing out, the _session_id key persists (its just the value of it changes). So rather than checking if there is a _session_id key, is there a way to check if it has been modified, so that when the user signs out, if the session key has been modified, then it goes back to content of abc server (The reason why is because I really dont want to change the code of the xyz server just to meet the needs of abc server)

Comment: Not without keeping a session in the `abc` server - which Apache doesn't do.  I'm assuming that the same issue will occur if someone visits the sign-in page but doesn't actually sign in; they'll probably end up with a session id cookie.  In order for the `abc` server to reliably proxy, it needs something to be able to watch and decide where to send a request.  Sounds like that cookie won't work; are there any other cookies present that could be looked at?  Maybe HTTP headers?

Comment: I looked at http headers and other than cookie nothing really persists during session. I will have to address that issue programmatically. The only other issue I have is that xyz is one of a few virtual hosts set up on xyz server that all resolve to same ip. So I am thinking of setting the specific virtual host to port 88 and then in the proxy reference port 88 rather than port 80 so it knows exactly what site to load.